# How to control the text color of an NSTextField when it is displaying a placeholder marker?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstextfield

When the NSTextField (Label) is bound to a controller selection with bindings, and I have specified placeholder values for the Multiple Values Marker, No Selection Marker, etc it draws the text with a gray color that does not show up well on a dark background.

Is there a way to change the text color it uses to display the placeholder text?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use an attributed string specifying the color you want, like this:

```
NSDictionary *blueDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSColor blueColor]
                        forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
NSAttributedString *blueString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"test"
                                attributes: blueDict] autorelease];
```

Then you can either set the placeholder attributed string directly:

```
[[field cell] setPlaceholderAttributedString: blueString];
```

or do it through a binding, for example:

```
[field2 bind: @"value" toObject: [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
        withKeyPath: @"foo"
        options: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: blueString forKey: NSNullPlaceholderBindingOption]];
```

Comment: I tried setting the placeholder attributed string directly but when I click on the text field, then the placeholder disappears, is this normal or is there a way around this to get the placeholder to stay until a character is typed.

Comment: That depends on the OS X version - I believe the behavior you want was added in 10.7. In earlier versions the placeholder string disappears when the field receives keyboard focus ("becomes key" in Cocoa terminology).

Comment: I am using 10.8.3 and still seeing this issue. The placeholder vanishes once I click on the text field or if I make it the first responder programatically.

Comment: I see what you mean now - it looks like this is a difference with setting placeholder *attributed* strings (which don't stay around when the field receives keyboard focus) rather than placeholder strings (which do).  I made an incorrect assumption that the two were more related.  I'd suggest you file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to make your own "palceholder". I mean your can show a label over your textfield with any text patameters you want.